# Show text in Textview even if too long for layout

Tags: android, textview

I want to show a dynamic string in an textview. This textview can take over a length to a certain degree. Is it possible to let the too long string somehow run through the textview? What I mean: initially the Textview should show as much letters as it can, but lets say after 5 seconds it slowly iterates through the hole string. This would make the whole text readable. The user should not have to interact with the ui.

Comment: Yes, you can have scrollbars in your TextViews. Just don't set the `singleLine` attribute to true. You can use the `maxLines` attribute to set the desired exact height in lines. For reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: What do you mean? You can assign any length string (within reason) to TextView. It'll either crop it if it can't show everything or you can use android:ellipsize="true" to show "..." at the end of the textview. Alternatively, you can make your textview multi line so that it automatically adds new lines to cover all your text.

Comment: if you want the long text to be displayed in your TextView, just put it inside a ScrollView without defining any attributes of ( maxLines etc )

Comment: What I mean: initially the Textview should show as much letters as it can, but lets say after 5 seconds it slowly iterates through the hole string. This would make the whole text readable. The user should not have to interact with the ui. any idea?

Comment: You mean that your string will be dispayed as paragraphs, for example, for the first 5 seconds, you will display 200 characters, and 200 characters in the second 5 seconds, etc until reaching the end of the text string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to show a large text in a small layout or UI component then there is a global understanding to show part of the text i.e. substring appended with "..."

For e.g., If I have a String of 18 Characters and my UI component can only show 10 characters, then I will get a substring consisting of characters from index 0 to 7th and append "..." and show it

Hope this helps

Comment: What I mean: initially the Textview should show as much letters as it can, but lets say after 5 seconds it slowly iterates through the hole string. This would make the whole text readable. any idea how to do that?

Comment: Hmmm.... on that case run a timer and do a method call at the end which will change the current substring depending upon its length and "..." may exist on both ends. Then repeat the timer call until the last index of substring is equal to last index of Original string. I am not a android developer, so don't know exact syntax to write this logic.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<TextView
    android:text="aaaa bbbbb  ccccc ddddd eee ffff gggg hhhh iiii jjjjj kkkkkk lllll mmmmm nnnnn oooo aaaa bbbbb  ccccc ddddd eee ffff gggg hhhh iiii jjjjj kkkkkk lllll mmmmm nnnnn oooo aaaa bbbbb  ccccc ddddd eee ffff gggg hhhh iiii jjjjj kkkkkk lllll mmmmm nnnnn oooo" 
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

If you dont want it to repeat itself over and over just remove this line:

```
android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
```

Edit:

Ok, so here is a quick explanation. You have to set the TextViews ellipsize type to "Marquee". This will auto slide it from left to right. You can set the amount of times it should repeat itself, if any. The line

```
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="YOUR_REPEAT_COUNT_HERE"
```

sets the amount of times it will repeat itself.

You will also need the following lines for the marquee to work properly:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Here is a link of the google TextView Api:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize

Comment: If possible, try to explain why this answer may help the OP. Code-only answer might confuse OP and other viewers eventhough it solves their problem.